# MVC3, RavenDb, Web Publishing, and Source Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mercurial, ravendb

I am using the embedded version of RavenDb and have put the physical database in the App_Data folder, based on this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh547101.aspx. My first question is, what portions of the db need to be committed to the SCM repo?

The second question is, My workflow is such that I'll also use web publishing directly from my laptop, are there any concerns using this methodology?

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to put your database under source-control since your documents have no particular schema. They will be created on the fly when serialized into json. So as long as you check in your C# classes, you're all fine.

Comment: I actually prime the database with millions of records first, then another process that's out of scope for this question will keep it synchronized with the mother-ship.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is the question then?

Comment: Yeah, I think I took the example from MSDN too literally. I'll move the db out to a folder that the site can access. That answers both questions at once. Thanks Daniel.

Answer (score 1):

First, are you aware that RavenDB uses the AGPL license?  This license requires that you publish your project as open source if you are not paying for a commercial license.

They do offer free licensing in some cases but you must contact them and get a license. Check their licensing page for more details.

Second, You proably shouldn't check your database into your SCM.  Databases change frequently, and SCM is designed for files that not constantly changing.  You might want to check in your database schema as it changes... but not the database itself.

Regarding your second question, i'm not sure what concerns you're talking about.  Can you be more clear about what your concerns are?

Comment: You don't need a license for development, so he doesn't need to worry about that. You are talking about checking in the schema into SCM - do you actually know ravendb? There is no schema to check in and this is a good thing.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.. we meet again.. There is no schema per se, just all the files that make up the db, starting from the root folder on down through the indexes. and the data file

Comment: @DanielLang - Regardless of the hype, there *IS* still a schema, it's just a dynamically created one.  If you try to deserialize your records to the wrong object versions, you have a problem.  That's a schema.

Comment: I agree, but it's not a schema in a tradition sense of a database, since it is created dynamically at serialization time. You are right, of course - there is a schema/structure.

Comment: @DanielLang - You don't need a license for development, but you do when you want to use it for production.  I just wanted to make sure the asker knew that it wasn't GPL'd and that there are requirements for the finished product.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to make sure the asker isn't thinking he cannot use RavenDB with his SCM because he needs a license for that. Thanks for clarifying.